# how to repeat while loop but not from beginning

Tags: python, while-loop

right now i have been learning python like 2 weeks. and i want to solve this code.

```
number = 0
while True:
    input_1 = int(input('First Number: '))
    number += 1
    if input_1 == 1:
        input_2 = int(input('Second Number: '))
        number += 2
        if input_2 == 2:
            input_3 = int(input('Third Number: '))
            number += 3
            if input_3 == 3:
                break
            else:
                number -= 6
                continue
        else:
            number -= 3
            continue

    else:
        number -= 1
        continue
print(number)
```

so basically i want to repeat while loop not for beginning, as example when im in input_2 and the condition get in to else, i want the code is looping to input_2 again. thanku for all of ur answer

Comment: Your loop exits whenever the third input is `3` and keeps looping otherwise, I assume that's intentional? Can you explain what you're trying to achieve with this code? You could nest while loops - as a direct answer to your question, but I wonder what you're trying to do here, because there's probably a less confusing way to do it.

Comment: thankyou so much for ur help!. actually this is not the code that I want to ask, but ur comment make me get the logic and solved my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because all your loops share similar behavior, the best approach to this would be to loop through variables based on the current stage rather than have nested loops:

```py
stage = 1
final_stage = 3
prompts = ['First Number: ', 'Second Number: ', 'Third Number: ']
increment = [1, 2, 3]
decrement = [1, 3, 6]

number = 0
while True:
    input_num = int(input(prompts[stage - 1]))
    number += increment[stage - 1]
    if input_num == stage:
        if stage == final_stage:
            break

        stage += 1
    else:
        number -= decrement[stage - 1]

print(number)
```

Comment: thanku jeremye for ur help!. even i still don't understand 100% what you're write maybe because I am still new in coding and python. i will try to remember it and remake what you're answer to simmiliar program